# PCs Front USB panel connections

Tags: usb, case-mods

I've made a custom PC case and now I want to add front USB panel into it.

I've made two USB holes in the case without audio.
I don't know any circuit diagram so I'm here.

So how should I make the connections for that USB panel?

Comment: [USB pinout](http://pinouts.ru/Slots/USB_pinout.shtml), pinouts of USB headers on your motherboard depend on the motherboard (look in the manual; locate manual online, if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Very snazzy case.

Your answer can be found in a couple of places.

First, your motherboard.  If it supports the ports there, then you will want to make sure you have the right plugs or adapters to connect to them.  If you have a lot of ports on the back then look at how they are hooked up and compare that to the cables that came with your front-panel ports.

Alternatively, if there are no available motherboard ports, you may want to pick up a USB3 board just to support high-speed ports on the front.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My motherboard do have ports for front panel. But my old case didn't came with any front USB panel so want to make one without audio port and struk here. Buying new will take a week and will cost more.

Comment: You can get front panel boards for $10-$20 on Amazon. Much quicker _and_ cheaper than you could do yourself...

Comment: They don't deliver where I live. That's what the problem is. Also the holes I made is of custom size. Apart from each other. So even if I bought it, I will have to make them as I wanted. For now I have blank USB slots, PC board, soldering machine, wires and everything. So I think I should make one.

Comment: Whatever works for you.  In my case, I disconnected some on the back and installed a panel in the front where the floppy drive would be and wired them into the motherboard where the back-side ports were connected.  I also bought a neat little rig that sits up on my desk that provides 3 USB 2 ports and slots for SD cards for the camera.  Makes life a lot easier.  I plugged that thing into a backside port.  It makes the wireless keyboard and mouse work better and such, but isn't build for high speed.

Answer (score 0):

Three options. If your board has an internal header of 1" pins for 2 usb ports, a standard internal usb connector would work. If not, then use a PCI usb card for the same. Or you can use a usb male to usb female, a usb extender cable to run two external usb ports on the back to the front.